# wrapper to make anonymous enums proper types

Tags: c, c++11, enums

I have some typedef'd enums that are included from c-code, i.e. they are available in the form

```cpp
typedef enum {FOO=3, BAR=5} my_enum;
```

and I would like use it in C++ code in a typesafe manner while leaving the `enum` names (FOO and BAR) and values (3 and 5) and their association unmodified.

Are there any best practices or patterns like template wrappers, that can be recommended to accomplish that, say in C++11 or higher?

Comment: Can you please provide an example where you can't use `typedef`'d name in overload resolution, as you've mentioned in the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 onwards you can declare these types as an `enum class` to get the type safety, but you must qualify usages with the name of the enum.

```
enum class my_enum {
    FOO=3,
    BAR=5
};

void my_func(my_enum e) {

}

int main() {
  my_enum test_enum = my_enum::FOO;
  my_func(test_enum);
}
```

If we changed the above definition of `test_enum` to `my_enum test_enum = FOO;` we'd get the error:

`13:23: error: 'FOO' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: maybe I should have clarified that the C-headers have to be used as is and that it is not permitted to modify them, therefore I am looking for a way to keep the C++ wrapper in synch with the C enums even in case the C enums get modified by the person that controls corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if a

```
using
```

declaration works; at least the following compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum{A=0, B=1, C=2} my_enum;
typedef enum{H=0, I=1, J=2} your_enum;

using namespace std;
using my_wrapper = my_enum;
using your_wrapper = your_enum;

int g(my_wrapper w)
{
    return (int)w-10;
}

int g(your_wrapper w)
{
    return (int)w+10;
}


int main() {
    my_wrapper b=my_wrapper::B;
    your_wrapper j=your_wrapper::J;
    cout << g(b) << "\n";
    cout << g(j) << "\n";
}
```